# Vue, change native event not working, input native does

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a question and maybe a Vue bugg.

I have a custom component that needs a @change.native event. But it does not trigger anything and I could not find anything about this issue myself.

So i tried some different stuff and like @click.native and @input.native does work. Even tho @input.native works and do the trick i want to, i still want to know why the change event does not work.

Anybody? Else I should report this.

Vue version: 2.5.2

```
<custom-input type="search" 
              placeholder="search" 
              v-model="search" 
              @input.native="change" />
```

Comment: What does your `custom-input` template look like?

Comment: Here's an example implementation of your `custom-input` where the `change` event is handled as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/p8v2adyt/1/

Comment: Ah nvm my mistake. So it does work, but i should unfocus the input (click somewhere outside the input) to make it trigger. My mistake of understanding the change event.

Answer (score 2):

If the `<input />` inside the custom component is a child element of another element, then the event listener bound by the `.native` modifier will not be reached, since it is listening to the event of a different element.

custom-input.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input :value="someValue" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value']
}
</script>
```

so if you have this scenario, then the `@change.native` will be bound on the `<div>` (the wrapper).
(sadly) You need to manually propagate the event manually.

Comment: Ah nvm my mistake. So it does work, but i should unfocus the input (click somewhere outside the input) to make it trigger. My mistake of understanding the change event.